# Implicit super constructor QueryDslRepositorySupport() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: jpa, spring-roo, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use **Spring Roo** + **Spring Data** + **QueryDSL** and I have the following classes/interfaces:

```
public interface FamilyAdvertisementRepositoryCustom {
}

@RooJpaRepository(domainType = FamilyAdvertisement.class)
public interface FamilyAdvertisementRepository extends FamilyAdvertisementRepositoryCustom {
}

public class FamilyAdvertisementRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements FamilyAdvertisementRepositoryCustom {
   //NO CONSTRUCTOR
}
```

all in following package: `com.bignibou.repository;`

With following config:

```
<repositories base-package="com.bignibou.repository" />
```

However, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) on project bignibou: Compiler errors : [ERROR] error at public class FamilyAdvertisementRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements FamilyAdvertisementRepositoryCustom { [ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [ERROR] /home/julien/Documents/donnees/projets/site-garde-enfants/java/bignibou/src/main/java/com/bignibou/repository/FamilyAdvertisementRepositoryImpl.java:5:0::0 Implicit super constructor QueryDslRepositorySupport() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

It seems the ***QueryDslRepositorySupport*** class no longer has a default constructor whereas this was the case before. Why is that??

What I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change was introduced to force the `Builder` being returned from `getBuilder()` into a single domain type. Simply create a constructor without arguments and invoke the super class' constructor with the domain type you implement the repository for.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. Done. I was just concerned this would break existing applications upgrading to the current version of Spring data jpa...

Comment: Right, that's why we introduced it in a major version bump (to 1.2 IIRC).